# Delegate isn't working

Tags: c#, delegates

I come across a change in a program which my current infastructure couldn't handle and was become too long: I had to stop using such absolute code and move towards Object Orientated.

**Repetition issue:**

```
List<string[]> logos = new List<string[]>();
string[] tempLogo = new string[2];
tempLogo[0] = "FRONT EMB";
tempLogo[1] = front_emb;
logos.Add(tempLogo);
tempLogo[0] = "back EMB";
tempLogo[1] = back_emb;
logos.Add(tempLogo);
```

**Became:**

```
delegate string addLogo(string x); // Namespace area

public static void IntergrateLogo(string toAdd, string name) // Inside Class
{
    string[] tempLogo = new string[2];
    tempLogo[0] = name;
    tempLogo[1] = toAdd;
    logos.Add(tempLogo);
}

// Main method
addLogo adl = new addLogo(IntegrateLogo);
List<string[]> logos = new List<string[]>();
adl(front_emb,"FRONT EMB");
adl(back_emb,"BACK EMB");
```

**Issue:**

> ***1.*** *The name 'logos' does not exist in the current context*
>
> ***2.*** *No overload for 'IntergrateLogo' matches delegate 'addLogo'*
>
> ***3.*** *Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement*

**Question:**

From my, very low, knowledge on delegates, they should 'mimic' the main method environment; therefore, my List - `logos`, should be able to be seen and used inside the `IntergrateLogo` method.

Well, that understanding went out the window when I couldn't get this working.

I am not asking for a fix here, I just want a better understanding with delegates because everywhere I search, it says that it allows the context environment scope to be accessed within a method but clearly that is not working here.

**Is there a way that `logos` can be seen within the `IntergrateLogo` method by using a delegate?**

Comment: correct, 1.. logos is defined wherever you're calling your main method - its not available outside that method.  2. IntergrateLogo has different parameters to AddLogo, so no it wont match, 3...not sure where this comes from but it could be a result of the above

Comment: the signature of a method must be identical to a the delegate that you want to use to invoke the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that logos can be seen within the IntergrateLogo method by using a delegate?

Not when it's a local variable, no.

It's not really clear why you'd use delegates for this at all though. I wouldn't even use a method, but instead write:

```
List<string[]> logos = new List<string[]>
{
    // TODO: Rename front_emb and back_emb to follow .NET naming conventions
    new[] { front_emb, "FRONT EMB" },
    new[] { back_emb, "BACK EMB" },
};
```

I'd also consider creating a `Logo` class rather than using string arrays, at which point you'd have:

```
List<Logo> logos = new List<Logo>
{
    new Logo(front_emb, "FRONT EMB"),
    new Logo(back_emb, "BACK EMB"),
}
```

That's looking *considerably* tidier, IMO.

Comment: I never thought about the Class idea, been a long 4 day weekend and not even Coffee is switching my brain on. Appreciated this! This should solve my issue and I'll look more into delegates without local variables. & Just to quickly answer why I choose delegate approach is because I thought that `logos` list could be accessed through the method rather than me passing the parameters all the time like you would in a normal method - suppose I was just being lazy.